# Trouble starting OpenVPN for the first time. Address already in use (errno=98)

Tags: iptables, vpn, openvpn

I have installed and configured OpenVPN on CentOS 7 for the first time and can't seem to get it to start. I am attempting to create a VPN in bridge mode so that connected clients are assigned IPs in the 192.168.2.0/24 range and so that they can talk with our servers on the 192.168.1.0/24 range. I would really appreciate any advice on where I'm making a mistake on configuration. Thank you!

Below are the errors I am running into and related config files / iptables.

**systemctl status openvpn@server.service:**

```
● openvpn@server.service - OpenVPN Robust And Highly Flexible Tunneling Application On server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/openvpn@.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2020-03-04 13:47:57 EST; 34min ago
  Process: 30058 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/openvpn --cd /etc/openvpn/ --config %i.conf (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 30058 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Mar 04 13:47:57 atlgate systemd[1]: Starting OpenVPN Robust And Highly Flexible Tunneling Application On server...
Mar 04 13:47:57 atlgate openvpn[30058]: Options error: In [CMD-LINE]:1: Error opening configuration file: server.conf
Mar 04 13:47:57 atlgate openvpn[30058]: Use --help for more information.
Mar 04 13:47:57 atlgate systemd[1]: openvpn@server.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Mar 04 13:47:57 atlgate systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenVPN Robust And Highly Flexible Tunneling Application On server.
Mar 04 13:47:57 atlgate systemd[1]: Unit openvpn@server.service entered failed state.
Mar 04 13:47:57 atlgate systemd[1]: openvpn@server.service failed.
```

**openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/server/server.conf:**

```
Wed Mar  4 14:25:35 2020 OpenVPN 2.4.8 x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu [Fedora EPEL patched] [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on Nov  1 2019
Wed Mar  4 14:25:35 2020 library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017, LZO 2.06
Wed Mar  4 14:25:35 2020 NOTE: when bridging your LAN adapter with the TAP adapter, note that the new bridge adapter will often take on its own IP address that is different from what the LAN adapter was previously set to
Wed Mar  4 14:25:35 2020 Diffie-Hellman initialized with 2048 bit key
Wed Mar  4 14:25:35 2020 TUN/TAP device tap0 opened
Wed Mar  4 14:25:35 2020 TUN/TAP TX queue length set to 100
Wed Mar  4 14:25:35 2020 Could not determine IPv4/IPv6 protocol. Using AF_INET
Wed Mar  4 14:25:35 2020 Socket Buffers: R=[212992->212992] S=[212992->212992]
Wed Mar  4 14:25:35 2020 TCP/UDP: Socket bind failed on local address [AF_INET][undef]:1194: Address already in use (errno=98)
Wed Mar  4 14:25:35 2020 Exiting due to fatal error
Wed Mar  4 14:25:35 2020 Closing TUN/TAP interface
```

**service.conf:**

```
# Which local IP address should OpenVPN
# listen on? (optional)
;local a.b.c.d

# Which TCP/UDP port should OpenVPN listen on?
# If you want to run multiple OpenVPN instances
# on the same machine, use a different port
# number for each one.  You will need to
# open up this port on your firewall.
port 1194

# TCP or UDP server?
;proto tcp
proto udp

# "dev tun" will create a routed IP tunnel,
# "dev tap" will create an ethernet tunnel.
# Use "dev tap0" if you are ethernet bridging
# and have precreated a tap0 virtual interface
# and bridged it with your ethernet interface.
# If you want to control access policies
# over the VPN, you must create firewall
# rules for the the TUN/TAP interface.
# On non-Windows systems, you can give
# an explicit unit number, such as tun0.
# On Windows, use "dev-node" for this.
# On most systems, the VPN will not function
# unless you partially or fully disable
# the firewall for the TUN/TAP interface.
dev tap0
;dev tun

# Windows needs the TAP-Win32 adapter name
# from the Network Connections panel if you
# have more than one.  On XP SP2 or higher,
# you may need to selectively disable the
# Windows firewall for the TAP adapter.
# Non-Windows systems usually don't need this.
;dev-node MyTap

# SSL/TLS root certificate (ca), certificate
# (cert), and private key (key).  Each client
# and the server must have their own cert and
# key file.  The server and all clients will
# use the same ca file.
#
# See the "easy-rsa" directory for a series
# of scripts for generating RSA certificates
# and private keys.  Remember to use
# a unique Common Name for the server
# and each of the client certificates.
#
# Any X509 key management system can be used.
# OpenVPN can also use a PKCS #12 formatted key file
# (see "pkcs12" directive in man page).
ca /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/issued/server.crt
key /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/private/server.key
#original:
;key server.key  # This file should be kept secret

# Diffie hellman parameters.
# Generate your own with:
#   openssl dhparam -out dh2048.pem 2048
#suggested from setup guide
dh /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/dh.pem
#Original
#dh dh2048.pem

# Network topology
# Should be subnet (addressing via IP)
# unless Windows clients v2.0.9 and lower have to
# be supported (then net30, i.e. a /30 per client)
# Defaults to net30 (not recommended)
topology subnet

# Configure server mode and supply a VPN subnet
# for OpenVPN to draw client addresses from.
# The server will take 10.8.0.1 for itself,
# the rest will be made available to clients.
# Each client will be able to reach the server
# on 10.8.0.1. Comment this line out if you are
# ethernet bridging. See the man page for more info.
;server 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0

# Maintain a record of client <-> virtual IP address
# associations in this file.  If OpenVPN goes down or
# is restarted, reconnecting clients can be assigned
# the same virtual IP address from the pool that was
# previously assigned.
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt

# Configure server mode for ethernet bridging.
# You must first use your OS's bridging capability
# to bridge the TAP interface with the ethernet
# NIC interface.  Then you must manually set the
# IP/netmask on the bridge interface, here we
# assume 10.8.0.4/255.255.255.0.  Finally we
# must set aside an IP range in this subnet
# (start=10.8.0.50 end=10.8.0.100) to allocate
# to connecting clients.  Leave this line commented
# out unless you are ethernet bridging.
server-bridge 192.168.2.1 255.255.255.0 192.168.2.100 192.168.2.200

# Configure server mode for ethernet bridging
# using a DHCP-proxy, where clients talk
# to the OpenVPN server-side DHCP server
# to receive their IP address allocation
# and DNS server addresses.  You must first use
# your OS's bridging capability to bridge the TAP
# interface with the ethernet NIC interface.
# Note: this mode only works on clients (such as
# Windows), where the client-side TAP adapter is
# bound to a DHCP client.
server-bridge

# Push routes to the client to allow it
# to reach other private subnets behind
# the server.  Remember that these
# private subnets will also need
# to know to route the OpenVPN client
# address pool (10.8.0.0/255.255.255.0)
# back to the OpenVPN server.
push "route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0"
;push "route 192.168.20.0 255.255.255.0"

# To assign specific IP addresses to specific
# clients or if a connecting client has a private
# subnet behind it that should also have VPN access,
# use the subdirectory "ccd" for client-specific
# configuration files (see man page for more info).

# EXAMPLE: Suppose the client
# having the certificate common name "Thelonious"
# also has a small subnet behind his connecting
# machine, such as 192.168.40.128/255.255.255.248.
# First, uncomment out these lines:
;client-config-dir ccd
;route 192.168.40.128 255.255.255.248
# Then create a file ccd/Thelonious with this line:
#   iroute 192.168.40.128 255.255.255.248
# This will allow Thelonious' private subnet to
# access the VPN.  This example will only work
# if you are routing, not bridging, i.e. you are
# using "dev tun" and "server" directives.

# EXAMPLE: Suppose you want to give
# Thelonious a fixed VPN IP address of 10.9.0.1.
# First uncomment out these lines:
;client-config-dir ccd
;route 10.9.0.0 255.255.255.252
# Then add this line to ccd/Thelonious:
#   ifconfig-push 10.9.0.1 10.9.0.2

# Suppose that you want to enable different
# firewall access policies for different groups
# of clients.  There are two methods:
# (1) Run multiple OpenVPN daemons, one for each
#     group, and firewall the TUN/TAP interface
#     for each group/daemon appropriately.
# (2) (Advanced) Create a script to dynamically
#     modify the firewall in response to access
#     from different clients.  See man
#     page for more info on learn-address script.
;learn-address ./script

# If enabled, this directive will configure
# all clients to redirect their default
# network gateway through the VPN, causing
# all IP traffic such as web browsing and
# and DNS lookups to go through the VPN
# (The OpenVPN server machine may need to NAT
# or bridge the TUN/TAP interface to the internet
# in order for this to work properly).
;push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"

# Certain Windows-specific network settings
# can be pushed to clients, such as DNS
# or WINS server addresses.  CAVEAT:
# http://openvpn.net/faq.html#dhcpcaveats
# The addresses below refer to the public
# DNS servers provided by opendns.com.
;push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.222.222"
;push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.220.220"

# Uncomment this directive to allow different
# clients to be able to "see" each other.
# By default, clients will only see the server.
# To force clients to only see the server, you
# will also need to appropriately firewall the
# server's TUN/TAP interface.
;client-to-client

# Uncomment this directive if multiple clients
# might connect with the same certificate/key
# files or common names.  This is recommended
# only for testing purposes.  For production use,
# each client should have its own certificate/key
# pair.
#
# IF YOU HAVE NOT GENERATED INDIVIDUAL
# CERTIFICATE/KEY PAIRS FOR EACH CLIENT,
# EACH HAVING ITS OWN UNIQUE "COMMON NAME",
# UNCOMMENT THIS LINE OUT.
;duplicate-cn

# The keepalive directive causes ping-like
# messages to be sent back and forth over
# the link so that each side knows when
# the other side has gone down.
# Ping every 10 seconds, assume that remote
# peer is down if no ping received during
# a 120 second time period.
keepalive 10 120

# For extra security beyond that provided
# by SSL/TLS, create an "HMAC firewall"
# to help block DoS attacks and UDP port flooding.
#
# Generate with:
#   openvpn --genkey --secret ta.key
#
# The server and each client must have
# a copy of this key.
# The second parameter should be '0'
# on the server and '1' on the clients.
;tls-auth ta.key 0 # This file is secret

# Select a cryptographic cipher.
# This config item must be copied to
# the client config file as well.
# Note that v2.4 client/server will automatically
# negotiate AES-256-GCM in TLS mode.
# See also the ncp-cipher option in the manpage
cipher AES-256-CBC

# Enable compression on the VPN link and push the
# option to the client (v2.4+ only, for earlier
# versions see below)
;compress lz4-v2
;push "compress lz4-v2"

# For compression compatible with older clients use comp-lzo
# If you enable it here, you must also
# enable it in the client config file.
;comp-lzo

# The maximum number of concurrently connected
# clients we want to allow.
;max-clients 100

# It's a good idea to reduce the OpenVPN
# daemon's privileges after initialization.
#
# You can uncomment this out on
# non-Windows systems.
;user nobody
;group nobody

# The persist options will try to avoid
# accessing certain resources on restart
# that may no longer be accessible because
# of the privilege downgrade.
persist-key
persist-tun

# Output a short status file showing
# current connections, truncated
# and rewritten every minute.
status openvpn-status.log

# By default, log messages will go to the syslog (or
# on Windows, if running as a service, they will go to
# the "\Program Files\OpenVPN\log" directory).
# Use log or log-append to override this default.
# "log" will truncate the log file on OpenVPN startup,
# while "log-append" will append to it.  Use one
# or the other (but not both).
;log         openvpn.log
;log-append  openvpn.log

# Set the appropriate level of log
# file verbosity.
#
# 0 is silent, except for fatal errors
# 4 is reasonable for general usage
# 5 and 6 can help to debug connection problems
# 9 is extremely verbose
verb 3

# Silence repeating messages.  At most 20
# sequential messages of the same message
# category will be output to the log.
;mute 20

# Notify the client that when the server restarts so it
# can automatically reconnect.
explicit-exit-notify 1
```

**ifconfig -a: (external IP modified)**

```
enp12s0: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 00:1e:4f:c9:8a:86  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 16  

enp2s4f0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.34  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::2e0:edff:fe0d:2284  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:e0:ed:0d:22:84  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 133312286  bytes 32872147591 (30.6 GiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 127  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 243540257  bytes 353658118727 (329.3 GiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 24  

enp2s4f1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 55.50.033.1  netmask 255.255.255.248  broadcast 64.61.144.7
        inet6 fe80::2e0:edff:fe0d:2285  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:e0:ed:0d:22:85  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 243468624  bytes 353664332100 (329.3 GiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 157  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 132681627  bytes 32817632124 (30.5 GiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 28  

enp3s6f0: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 00:e0:ed:0d:22:86  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 29  

enp3s6f1: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 00:e0:ed:0d:22:87  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 30  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 46  bytes 3844 (3.7 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 46  bytes 3844 (3.7 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

tap0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.2.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.2.255
        inet6 fe80::2012:feff:fe7c:ffd4  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 22:12:fe:7c:ff:d4  txqueuelen 100  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 2 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

tun1: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.41.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  destination 192.168.41.1
        inet6 fe80::a93e:39b1:d3b6:6669  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 100  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 10993  bytes 660776 (645.2 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

**iptables -L**

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:openvpn
RH-Firewall-1-INPUT  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW udp dpt:openvpn

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RH-Firewall-1-INPUT  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain RH-Firewall-1-INPUT (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp any
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW tcp dpt:ici
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW udp dpt:openvpn
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW tcp dpt:pptp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW tcp dpt:snapenetio
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW tcp dpt:optocontrol
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW tcp dpt:22020
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW udp dpt:isakmp
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW udp dpt:l2tp
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW udp dpt:ipsec-nat-t
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

Comment: something is already using port 1194.  What do you see from `ss -nlp | grep :1194`

Comment: hmmm: `udp    UNCONN     0      0         *:1194                  *:*                   users:(("openvpn",pid=1010,fd=6))`

Comment: So now I don't know if its actually running or not...but `systemctl status openvpn@server` shows `Failed to start OpenVPN Robust And Highly Flexible Tunneling Application On server.`

Comment: the output shows that something is running.  Perhaps you have another instance of openvpn.  Perhaps it got started incorrectly earlier.  You will have to investigate.  The `ss` output shows you the pid.

Comment: It looks there already openvpn running on the 1194 with the same subnet you have in your file. So check also if there is another systemd unit for the same configuration file

Comment: Thanks everyone, there was an openvpn already setup on 1194. Solved.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone, there was a previously configured session pf openvpn already running on this server. Solved.